# Grouping data with Export-Csv

Tags: powershell, csv

I have created a dynamic object that I wish to output to a CSV file. So far I have only done different variations of having values in one column, in one cell, or outputting a description of the object (such as string length).

My HashTable object is created along the lines of:

```
 $item = @{"Total"=0; "Complete"= 0}
 $obj=@{"AllCounted" = 0 }

 # gets outside data
 foreach($field in $data){

     $obj+=@{$field = $item}

     $obj[$field]+= @{ $subField = $item }
```

which results in the following object

```
 $obj{
      "AllCounted" = [int]
      "dynamicField1"= {
                             "Total"    =[int];
                             "Complete" =[int]
                             "SubField1" ={
                                             "Total"    =[int];
                                             "Complete" =[int]
                             }
                         }
      "dynamicField _ N"= {
                            "Total"    =[int];
                            "Complete" =[int]
                            "SubField _ N" ={
                                             "Total"    =[int];
                                             "Complete" =[int]
                             }
                        }
   }
```

My Goal is

```
 $obj.Keys|%{ 
         $_ +","+$obj[$_]["Total"]+","+ $obj[$_]["Complete"]  | Out-File "something.csv" -append"

         foreach($innerLoop in $obj[$_].Keys){
                 ","+ $_ +","+$obj[$_]["Total"]+","+ $obj[$_]["Complete"]  | Out-File "something.csv" -append"
        }

}
```

CSV Showing

```
 Field1  |  Total      | Complete
         |  SubField1  |  Total   | Complete 
         |  SubField2  |  Total   | Complete 
         |  SubField N |  Total   | Complete 


 Field2  |  Total      | Complete
         |  SubField1  |  Total   | Complete 
         |  SubField2  |  Total   | Complete 
         |  SubField N |  Total   | Complete 


 Field N |  Total      | Complete
         |  SubField1  |  Total   | Complete 
         |  SubField2  |  Total   | Complete 
         |  SubField N |  Total   | Complete
```

All out of ideas but still trying..

Comment: A CSV file can't group data like that. It's a representation of a flat table. You have one header row, in which the column headings are listed separated by commas, and one or more data rows in which the values for each record are listed separated by commas in the same order as the headings. Do you even want a CSV, or do you just want to output the data in the format shown in your last block? (in which case CSV is the wrong term, what you mean is "text file")

Comment: I need a CSV but when i run a command such as 
`"ColHeader1, ColHeader2" | Export-Csv "file.csv"`
the value does not show up in different columns. If i did I could use two for-each loops and manually print  the information in the format I wish. such as

`"Field N, Total , Complete"| Export-CSV "file.csv" -append`
`"  ,SubField1, Total , Complete"| Export-CSV "file.csv" -append`
which would be creating the format if the Comma actually Seperated the Value

Comment: Exp0rt-CSV creates a CSV file from Powershell objects, with each object property as a column in the CSV.  That means you have to create objects (not just hash tables).

Comment: what if i was creating CSV strings and Out-file instead of export-csv, is there a way to get that working properly? `" , Subfield N, Total" | Out-file "myFile.csv" -append`

Comment: You can, but I don't recommend it.  If you're going to use Powershell you need to learn to create and  use PS objects, so you might as well start now and do it right.